# Compress streaming data before sending

Tags: tar, netcat

The following is working as expected.

Sending server:

```
mysqldump db_name tbl_name -d | nc -l 1234
```

Receiving server:

```
nc 10.10.10.114 1234 | mysql -uroot -proot@123 test
```

When I am dumping to remote server, it takes a lot of time to transfer data. 
Is it possible to add tar **jcf -** and tar **jxf -** in this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
mysqldump db_name tbl_name -d | bzip2 -c | nc -l 1234
```

and

```
nc 101010.114 1234 | bzip2 -cd | mysql -uroot -proot@123 test
```

(Replace `bzip2` with `gzip` or some other compression program if you want; they all work much the same way in Linux)

There's no reason to use tar; you're just dumping data out of MySQL as a single chunk of text.  You're also using `nc` in what is generally considered a "backwards" way; typically the consumer of the data (`mysql` in this case) does the listening (but there's no actual difference in operation, it just "feels" weird).

Be warned, though, this method might not actually make anything go faster -- in my experience, the bottleneck in MySQL dumps/loads is MySQL, not the network (unless you're running this over a seriously bandwidth-constrained link).

Answer (score 0):

Piping through tar should work just fine.

Sending:

```
... | tar -cjf - | ...
```

Receiving

```
... | tar -xjf - | ...
```

You might want to use "z" instead as it uses gzip compression instead of the more expensive bzip2, but it depends on how fast it works for you.

Comment: I really don't understand the desire to use `tar` in this sort of pipeline.  There's no actual files involved.

Comment: # bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly; # error on receiving data

Comment: @womble Too early in the morning, didn't catch the whole 'lack of file' thing.